# PivotTable Drillthrough not supported

Tags: asp-classic, ms-office, olap

We migrated our old ASP app to ASP.NET and can't seem to figure out the cause of this error.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC EA 2; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Mon, 12 Oct 2009 20:50:06 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'PivotTable1.Drillthrough'
Line: 1173
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http:///DSS2009/HospitalVisitsCube.aspx

Before, the page was hosted on a Windows 2000 Server, IIS 5.0 and SQL Server 2000.  We migrated the app to a new environment: Windows 2003 Server, IIS 6.0, SQL Server 2005 w/ Analysis Services and now the pages are using ASP.NET (ASP.NET 2.0 to be exact).  Anyone have a clue as to what's happening and a possible solution?  My first thought was that IIS 6 supports ASP 3.0 which might have deprecated this method/property. However, I'm clueless and can't prove my theory because my ASP knowledge is very limited.  Does anyone have any clue aso to what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, there's a file that you need to make Office Web Component (OWC) work.  You need an .htc file called drillthrough.htc.  This file is required to make it work.